# What are some slang terms for "newspaper"?

Tags: slang

I'm looking for some slang terms for a newspaper, whether they are archaic terms that nobody has used in the past 70 years or modern, obscure terms.

Comment: I think this question is diametrically opposed to what I would like to think are EL&U's objectives. Firstly - obviously there are no 'correct' answers. Second, and more importantly, it's not really a request for 'descriptive terms for newspapers'. It's an invitation to see what poetic/evocative[/insulting?] turns of phrase we can come up with for a much-vilified sector of society. I really think this is something for Yahoo Answers or Urban Dictionary. I don't want to sound elitist, but I'd rather prefer EL&U to be above this sort of thing.

Comment: While I think policing for off-topic questions has its place (I voted with you on [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31145/5822)), I can't agree with you here. Apart from the fact that I spent a good bit of time turning up old slang terms for my answer, I also feel that this is a "practical, answerable question based on an actual problem" and that the answers here now provide a fairly comprehensive list that can't readily be found elsewhere online. Finding some answers insulting is not a good reason for closing. Also, I'd suggest writing your vote-to-close opinions as comments.

Comment: @Callithumpian: I take your point on board, and will consider the issue. I certainly didn't intend to denigrate your answer as such, and I recognise it would have taken time, effort, and consideration. Which is much to be valued. My problem is with the suitability of questions like this on EL&U. For the time being I will leave my 'answer' here (@Martha notwithstanding), pending maybe a bit of 'discussion' on meta.

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee: Again, point taken. I've no wish to offend anyone, including even a first-time OP who maybe should have gone elsewhere to start a 'slang-list' talking shop. The downvotes are noted, and if they're overwhelming in a few days I'll delete the answer. In the meantime I'd like to mull over the issue with or without useful contributing arguments on both sides.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Having said that, I do agree with you that a list-style question like this one isn't the best.

Comment: I think that even if this is not _exactly_ what EL&U was intended for, I think that it is still relatively on-topic. This is a question about the _English Language._ I'm a developer that often uses Stack Overflow; I'm working on an app/website and I need a name for it that sounds "newspapery." What better place to get an answer than to hop on over to another SE website. Granted, I won't be able to mark any answer as the "Accepted Answer," but I will surely upvote 
@Callithumpian for being so helpful.

Comment: Don't forget to consider the interest that some of the terms might pique in some people. I saw the term "jeames," and I haven't the slightest clue what it means, but I am surely curious about the etymology of this obscure word... to Google I go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ass-wipe

birdcage liner

black and white and "red" all over

bladder

blatter

blat

blanket

bunk sheet

butter wrapper

Captain Grimes

croaker

extra

fish wrapper

fly-blister

huey

jeames

long acre

leer

morning

nursery rhymes

pap

paper

post

red top

sheet

stiff

tab

tibby

toerag

weekly**

<sup>Sources: *[Cassell's Dictionary of Slang](http://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&dq=newspaper&q=newspaper#v=snippet&q=newspaper&f=false)*, *[The Slang Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=o0EqAAAAYAAJ&dq=newspaper&q=newpaper#v=onepage&q=newspaper&f=false)*, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=birdcage%20liner), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_riddle),</sup>

[Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/lists/newspaper-names)'s got a nice list of words used in actual newspaper names.

Comment: Alphabetized, very nice. The Wordnik list is proving very helpful.

Comment: @Nick: Found a bunch more and deleted some non-slang synonyms. (PS, if an answer is helpful you can up-vote it and/or check it.)

Answer (score 2):

**Rag**
**Tomorrow's fish-and-chip wrappers**
**Scandal sheet**
**Libel mill**
**The old grey lady** (specifically, the New York Times)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I can think of the following

> Tabloid
>
> Broadsheet
>
> The Rag
>
> Daily Snooze
>
> Scandal Sheets
>
> The Slimes (The Times)
>
> Linen Draper (Cockney Rhyming Slang for Newspaper)
>
> Currant Bun (The Sun)